# C# System.UnauthorizedAccessException, Cant read from a file

Tags: c#, file, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I want to write a simple program, that will be able to search for certain text in a file. When I try to run the program I get the following error: *System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Access to the path 'C:\Users\mansar\Desktop' is denied."*

I tried to run Visual Studio Code as administrator but that did not help. My user and the admin user should have full permission to the file though.

The code

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\mansar\Desktop");
        Console.WriteLine("text");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you expect to read all text from the folder `C:\Users\mansar\Desktop`? As in, it's a folder not a file.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yeah that makes sense, im a bit stupid sometimes, thanks tho ^^

Comment: No problems. I'm sure I've made that mistake myself on more than one occasion.

Answer (score 0):

when you try to access the folder IIS creates a connection using the IUSER_ComputerName account, where ComputerName is the IIS running server. By default, the IUSER_ComputerName account is a member of the Guests group. Try to grant access to IUSER_ComputerName to that folder. the guests group has some security restrictions.